# Can I perform an ANCOVA with an ordinal covariate?

Tags: ordinal-data, ancova

I want to do an ANCOVA, with age and education level as the covariates. However, Education level is divided in 7 categories, that are ordered from low to high. Participants thus have a score ranging from 1 to 7 on this variable (ordinal). My question is basically, can I use education level as a covariate in the ANCOVA?
I'm asking this because from what I've read it seems that the covariate has to be continuous, or else it is a fixed factor (categorical). But in my case, it isn't exactly continuous but also not purely categorical because there is an order in the numbers.